# Chern character of finite $CW$-complexes and rational Pontrjagin class of vector bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, characteristic-classes, chern-classes

Let $K$ be a finite $CW$-complex. Could you give any references or explanations for the following two items? I do not understand. Thanks!

(1). The Chern character from $\tilde{KO}^0(K)$ to the product of the rational cohomology groups $H^{4j}(K)$ is rationally an isomorphism.

(2). Therefore in order for a vector bundle $\xi$ on $K$ to be such that some multiple of it is trivial it is sufficient if the rational Pontryagin classes vanish.

Comment: For (1), see the post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223519/which-map-realizes-the-isomorphism-ko-nx-otimes-mathbbq-to-bigoplus-i-in For (2), the post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521448/triviality-of-vector-bundles-with-the-reduced-homology-of-base-space-entirely-to might be relevant.

Comment: @user43326 Please note that the question you linked for (1) deals with $K$-homology. For $K$-theory, the situation is simpler.